# Why does .apply work, but using the original function doesnt?

Tags: python, pandas, function, indexing, apply

Why does this work:

```
def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
        else: 
            return 24
    else:
        return Age

train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis =1)
```

But this doesn't?

```
cols = train[['Age','Pclass']]
impute_age(cols)
```

I get a key error with the second snippet, saying Key Error: 0. It looks like it's not able to access the '0' index, even though there is clearly a value in the first row of the train[['Age','Pclass']]? Is there something I'm not understanding with how .apply works? Thanks!

Comment: They are two very different things. The argument `cols` in the first case (with apply) is a `pd.Series`, i.e. you `apply` that to each column (equivalent to imput_age(train['Age'])`. On the second case, it's a data frame.

Comment: I'm like 99.9% positive you mean to call the first case with `axis=1`, though there are better ways to do this without `apply`. The Titanic dataset is small enough for it to not be too big of an issue.

Comment: Try impute_age(cols[0]), if you just want to make it work? .apply() is more like .foreach() in javascript.